# Perl regex matches string differently when providing it as variable

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a question regarding regex matching in Perl. See following code snippet:

```
my $r = '^\z';
my $s = "";
$r =~ /$s/ ? print "Match\n" : print "No match\n";

Output: Match
```

following snippet however prints:

```
my $r = '^\z';
$r =~ /""/ ? print "Match\n" : print "No match\n";

Output: No match
```

Why? Is this a Perl syntax thing I do not understand?

Comment: That's because the string doesn't contain two quotation marks (that's what `/""/` tries to match).

Comment: `/$s/` => `//` because $s is an empty string (and doesn't contain double quotes that only delimit the string)

Comment: Are you trying to use `^\z` as a regular expression? If so, it should be on the RHS, e.g. `$foo =~ /^\z/` will match if `$foo` is the empty string.

Comment: To get some insight, like @jabbas says, put `use re 'debug';` at the top of your `XX.pl` source. Also, read through the `perlop` manpage (quote-like operators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $s = "";
```

is the same as

```
my $s = '';
```

or

```
my $s = q();
```

i.e. it assings an *empty string* to `$s`.

In

```
$r =~ /""/
```

you're testing whether $r contains two double quotes.

To assign a pair of double quotes to $s, use

```
my $s = '""';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $r = '^\z';
$r =~ /""/ ? print "Match\n" : print "No match\n";
```

Here, $r is the test string. `/""/` is the regex.
There is no `""` in $r, so it does not match.

This `/""/` is a string delimited by `/` char, the result of which turns into a regex object.
It is equivalent to:

```
$str = '""';
$rx = qr/$str/;
```

Comment: Well, to be absolutely precise, `$str = 'some regex'; $rx = qr/$str/` is not *always* the same as `qr/some regex/`. Regex literals have slightly different parsing rules than strings, e.g. concerning backslash escapes and embedded code.`

Answer (score 1):

The $s variable is casted to nothing. You can check it by yourself, just add `use re 'debug';` in the code or add `-Mre=debug` to perl invocation:

first example

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -E '$r=q{^\z}; $s=""; $r =~ /$s/ ? say "Match" : say "No match"'
Compiling REx ""
Final program:
   1: NOTHING (2)
   2: END (0)
minlen 0
Matching REx "" against "^\z"
   0 <> <^\z>                |  1:NOTHING(2)
   0 <> <^\z>                |  2:END(0)
Match successful!
    Match
    Freeing REx: ""
```

second example

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -E '$r=q{^\z}; $r =~ /""/ ? say "Match" : say "No match"'
Compiling REx "%"%""
Final program:
   1: EXACT <""> (3)
   3: END (0)
anchored "%"%"" at 0 (checking anchored isall) minlen 2
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "%"%"" against "^\z"
Did not find anchored substr "%"%""...
Match rejected by optimizer
    No match
    Freeing REx: "%"%""
```